# How to use Lagrange multipliers on a constraint made of 2 curves?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Determine the largest and smallest value of

$$f (x, y ) = x^2 + x(y^2 − 1)$$

on the region given by $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $|y| \leq 2$.

So far I have only used Lagrange multipliers on smooth closed curves and this is a closed curve but this constraint is made of 2 curves and I've no idea how to solve it. Can someone help me?

The only thing I've managed to do is:

$$\nabla f = (2x + y^2 - 1, x)$$

The critical point can be found at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $y$ is equal  $2xy.$ Hence $x={1/2},$ $y=0$ is the only critical point inside the region. Then you need to study the behavior of $f$ on each of the four segments of the rectangle. This can be done straightforward as the function reduces to one variable on each segment separately.

Comment: Don't forget to check the endpoints of the interval.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the Lagrange multiplier method is not convenient in this particular example. The boundary consists of four line segments, for which analysis is simple.

For this example observe that
$$x^2-x=f(x,0)\le f(x,y)\le f(x,\pm 2)=x^2+3x$$
Hence it suffices to determine the maximal value of $x^2+3x$ and the minimal value of $x^2-x$ on the interval $[0,2].$ The maximal value of $x^2+3x$ is attained at $x=2$ and is equal $16.$ The minimal value of $x^2-x$ is attained at $x={1\over 2}$ and is equal $-{1\over 4}.$ Summarizing the maximal value of $f$ is attained at $(2,\pm 2)$ and the minimal value at $({1\over 2},0).$

Comment: where did you get g(x) from?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp For $|y|=2$ we get $f(x,y)=x^2+3x.$

Comment: I still don't understand this part too btw "For this example observe that for any fixed x
 the maximal value of f(x,y) is attained for |y|=2 and the minimal value for y=0"? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: For $x\ge 0$ the quantity $x^2+x(y^2-1)$ is increasing with respect to $y^2$, equivalently with respect to $|y|.$

Comment: ok but aren't we interested in the edge of the function and how exactly did you do that here?

Comment: I have re-edited. Hopefully it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction $0\le x\le 2$ can be condensed as $x(x-2)\le 0$ and equivalently $|y|\le 2$ as $y^2-4\le 0$ and the lagrangian can be stated as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = x^2 + x (y^2 - 1)+\lambda_1x(x-2)+\lambda_2(y^2-4)
$$